# Update a document in OrientDB by adding a JSON string containing a date

Tags: orientdb

How can a document be updated that contains an array of documents containing a date type. To give an example

```
update personaldata add inquiries = [{"validations":[],"@class":"inquiries","@type":"d","date":"2014-12-05"}]
```

If you run this in the orient studio you get a ClassCastException. Without the date field everything is fine. I should add that the fields are typed. The type of the date field is datetime. Without the typing everything is fine again. Any idea how this statement could be made to work?

Comment: which version of OrientDB?
Do you have the server log?

Comment: The version is 2.0-M2. The log does not contain more details: 2014-12-05 20:42:12:330 INFO OrientDB Server v2.0-M2 is active. [OServer]
2014-12-05 20:43:19:306 SEVE Internal server error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]

Answer (score 1):

try 
to set the field types in this way:

```
update personaldata add inquiries = [{"validations":[],"@class":"inquiries","@type":"d","date":"2014-12-05","@fieldTypes" : "date=a"}]
```

here the full type that you can use in schema-less mode when using JSON

http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/OrientDB-REST.html

Comment: Thanks! This did the job. The @fieldTypes must be set. I think this is really ugly, and I do not understand, why it isn't possible to deduce the metadata from the class definition. The silly thing is that you clutter up the instance with class metadata, that is common to all instances.

Comment: Did you declare a property date with  type DATE in your schema?
In that case should use the type declared

Comment: Yes, the type is declared as date. My remark was about the re-specification of the type on instance level: The database already knows that the type of the attribute is a date. Why do I have to declare this again with @fieldTypes?

Comment: yep. Greate! No fieldTypes required in M3. Now only the '@class' and '@type' remain as a pain in the ... Again: this info is available in the class / property definition. The property inquiries is defined as an embeddedlist of class inquiries. All required metadata is there. Why to re-specify it on instance level. It doesn't belong there.